# Configuración de Servlets en Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

mi página de inicio en mi Tomcat (index.html) posee una estructura de este estilo:

```
<frame src="http://localhost:8080/webAppName/carpetaservlet/servlet.nombre">
</frameset>
```

y mi estructura de carpetas está de la siguiente manera:

```
webAppName/WEB-INF/classes/servlet/nombre.class
```

Al intentar ejecutar la aplicación obviamente me marca que carpetaservlet/servlet.nombre no existe. Pero si cambio la ruta de mi frame a:

```
src="http://localhost:8080/webAppName/servlet/nombre"
```

y declaro mi servlet en web.xml como:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>nombre</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>servlet.nombre</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>nombre</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/servlet/nombre</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

jala perfecto. El problema es que el servlet nombre.class hace una redirección a si mismo usando la dirección de arriba ("http://localhost:8080/webAppName/carpetaservlet/servlet.nombre") pero como toma la carpeta raíz entonces cuando redirige queda como:

```
"http://localhost:8080/webAppName/servlet/servlet.nombre"
```

la cual me marca obviamente que no existe debido al servlet.nombre (el servlet. está de más)

Hay alguna forma de declarar en el web.xml mi servlet de tal forma que la dirección la tome de la forma correcta?

```
"http://localhost:8080/webAppName/carpetaservlet/servlet.nombre"
```

Por favor ayudaa